# Pivot table with Pandas

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I have a small issue trying to do a simple pivot with pandas. I have on one column some values that are entered more than once with a different value in a second column and a year on a third column. What i want to do is get a sum of the second column for the year, using as rows the values on the first column.

```
import pandas as pd 

year = 2022

base = pd.read_csv("Database.csv")
raw_monthly = pd.read_csv("Monthly.csv")
raw_types = pd.read_csv("types.csv")
monthly = raw_monthly.assign(Year= year)


ty= raw_types[['cparty', 'sales']]
typ= sec.rename(columns={"Sales": "sales"})
type= typ.assign(Year=year)

fin = pd.concat([base, monthly, type])
fin.drop(fin.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
currentYear = fin.loc[fin['Year'] == 2022]
final = pd.pivot_table(currentYear, index=['cparty', 'sales'], values='sales', aggfunc='sum')
```

With the above, I am getting this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbTm7.png), but what i want is to have
the 2 sales values of '3' for 2022 summed in a single value so later i can also break it down by year. Any help appreciated!

Edit: The issue seems to come from the fact that the 3 csvs are concatenated into a single dataframe. Doing the 3->1 CSV conversion manually in excel and then trying to use the Groupby answer works as intended, but it does not work if i try to automatically make the 3 CVS to 1 using the
fin = pd.concat([base, monthly, type])

The 3 csvs look like this.

Base looks like this:

```
    cparty   sales      year
0   50969   -146602.14  2016
1   51056   -104626.62  2016
2   51129   -101742.99  2016
3   51036   -81801.84   2016
4   51649   -35992.60   2016
```

monthly looks like this, missing the year

```
    cparty   sales
0   818243  -330,052.47
1   82827   -178,630.85
2   508637  -156,369.87
3   29253   -104,028.30
4   596037  -95,312.07
```

type is like this.

```
    cparty   sales
0   582454  -16,056.46
1   597321  24,336.16
2   567172  20,736.78
3   614070  18,590.45
4   5601295 -3,661.46
```

What i am attempting to do is add a new column for the last 2 to have the Year set as 2022, so that later i can do the groupby per year. When i try to concat the 3 csvs, it breaks down.

Comment: How does it looks like **currentYear**, could you show minimum reproducible data of it

Comment: It looks like this. https://imgur.com/a/qoriVUr

Comment: can you share this via `df.to_dict()`? This is much easier to reproduce than looking at a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried using `index=[‘Year’, ‘cparty’]` in your `pd.pivot_table` arguments? I’m not sure why you have ‘sales’ in there for the index.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `cparty` is a categorical metric

```
# create sales and retail dataframes with year
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'year':[2022, 2022, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2021, 2019, 2018],
        'cparty':['cparty1', 'cparty1', 'cparty1', 'cparty2', 'cparty2', 'cparty2', 'cparty2', 'cparty3', 'cparty4', 'cparty4', 'cparty4', 'cparty4'],
        'sales':[230, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100]
        })
df
###
    year   cparty  sales
0   2022  cparty1    230
1   2022  cparty1    100
2   2018  cparty1    200
3   2019  cparty2    300
4   2020  cparty2    400
5   2021  cparty2    500
6   2022  cparty2    600
7   2022  cparty3    700
8   2022  cparty4    800
9   2021  cparty4    900
10  2019  cparty4   1000
11  2018  cparty4   1100
```

```
output = df.groupby(['year','cparty']).sum()
output 
###
              sales
year cparty        
2018 cparty1    200
     cparty4   1100
2019 cparty2    300
     cparty4   1000
2020 cparty2    400
2021 cparty2    500
     cparty4    900
2022 cparty1    330
     cparty2    600
     cparty3    700
     cparty4    800
```

Filter by `year`

```
final = output.query('year == 2022')
final
###
              sales
year cparty        
2022 cparty1    330
     cparty2    600
     cparty3    700
     cparty4    800
```

Comment: This is a solution that works, if i try to use the first df, "base", which has values from 2016, up to 2022. The problem is that when i try to concat the two news dfs to the base, that come with Year 2022 that were added from the script itself, it throws errors and refuses to work. https://imgur.com/a/dYFKqau

Comment: It would help if you showed all dataframes you used with minimum reproducible data as I showed you(As you can see, you got tons of `cparty` numbers, for easy understanding, I chose cparty1, cparty2, etc.), what you got, and what's the result you want and how it looks like, it's tough to see the whole story with screenshots.

Comment: For instance, I showed you `df` via `print(df)`, so I can copy the text and post it here for you to understand what's the structure of my `df`.

Comment: Would you please show base, month, type minimum understandable dataframe so I can reconstruct myself

Comment: Hello Baron, I have edited the question to add the 3 different dataframes. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have figured out the issue.

```
result = res.groupby(['Year', 'cparty']).sum()
output = result.query('Year == 2022')

output
##
              sales
Year  cparty    
2022  3     -20409.04
      4      12064.34
      5      9656.64
      8081   51588.55
      8099   5625.22
... ...
```

Baron's groupby method was the way to go. The issue is that it only works if I have all the data in 1 csv from the beginning. I was trying to add the year manually for the 2 new csv that i concat to the base, setting Year = 2022. The errors come when i concat the 3 different CSVs. If i don't add the year = 2022 it works giving this:

```
    cparty  sales   Year
87174   3   -3.89   2022.0
27  3   -20,405.15  NaN
```

If i do .fillna(2022) then it won't work as expected.

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14252/1015456002.py:32: FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in DataFrameGroupBy.add is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .add, select only columns which should be valid for the function.
result = fin.groupby(['Year', 'cparty']).sum()

```
        cparty  sales   Year
87174   3   -3.89       2022.0
27      3   -20,405.15  2022.0
```

Adding the year but not doing the sum to have 'cparty' 3, 'sales' -20,409.04, Year 2022.

Any feedback appreciated.